# DocuSign_SuppressStartDialog option not refelcted on embeded powerform in docusign

Tags: docusignapi

DocuSign_SuppressStartDialog option not reflected on embedded Powerform in DocuSign.
I have done with updated XML file of resource in brands section

Answer (score 0):

It is solved by after applied to default to my created brand